# $-\Delta u =f $ for $f\in L^p(\Omega)$ implies $\nabla u \in L^p(\Omega)$

Tags: regularity-theory-of-pdes, elliptic-equations

I wonder if there is a quick&dirty proof of the following statement:
Assume $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ open and bounded with $C^1$-boundary and $p\geq 2$. The unique solution $u\in H^1_0(\Omega)$ of

$$-\Delta u=f ,\quad f\in L^p(\Omega)$$

is actually in $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ and its $W^{1,p}$-norm can be bounded by $|f|_{L^p}$.

Comment: How "quick and dirty" are we talking? I don't think there's any way other than via Calderón-Zygmund estimates in one form or another. There are some relatively simple proofs if you're happy to assume some black-box interpolation theorems however.

Comment: I think Calderón-Zygmund is even giving the estimate for the second derivative of u. I need only Du in Lp so I assumed this should be much easier and obtained by testing with a smartly choosen test function. Interpolation theorems are also okay for me.